# NSRangeException. For empty NSArray index 0 beyond bounds

Tags: ios, swift

I have products in an empty array. When the view appears sometimes it's giving exceptions, such as `Terminating due to NSRangeException`, `Index 0 beyond bounds for empty NSArray`. I want to conditionally check the first value of the array but I don't have a proper idea how to solve it. Can someone please suggest me how to sovle this. This code is on `ViewDidLoad` of a view controller.

[image]

```
MCIAPHelper.sharedInstance.requestProductsWithCompletionHandler({ (success, products) -> () in
    if success {
        NSLog("\(String(describing: products?.count)) product count")
        self.fetchedProducts = products as? [SKProduct]
        NSLog("\(self.fetchedProducts.count) fetched product")
        if let product = products?[0] as? SKProduct {    //getting exception in this line
            let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
            numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = NumberFormatter.Behavior.behavior10_4
            numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency
            numberFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale
            if let productPrice = numberFormatter.string(from: product.price) {
                self.purchaseFullVersionSubtitle.text = "Use this app forever for only \(productPrice)"
            }
        }
    } else {
        //TODO: Error Handling
    }
})
```

Can someone suggest how to solve this in Swift 3? Trying to access array `[0]` for an `NSArray` that is empty.

Comment: do you check that products array is not nil ?

Answer (score 0):

write this to check if your products array has any product

```
if products != nil && products!.count > 0
```

before this

```
if  let product = products?[0] as? SKProduct {    //getting exception in this line
                        let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
```

Comment: You can also use if let product = products?.first? as? SKProduct

Answer (score 0):

The Swift way to test for this condition is:

```
if let product = products?.first as? SKProduct {
    ....
}
```

This checks for three conditions in one expression:

1. Is `products` non nil?
2. Is there at least one element in products?
3. Is the first element of type `SKProduct`?

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this kind of problems with a safe subscript，it will never causes crash even your index out of bounds，here is the code:

```
extension Collection {
    subscript(safe index: Index) -> Generator.Element? {
        return index >= startIndex && index < endIndex ? self[index] : nil
    }
}
```

Comment: You can use it like this: 
`if let product = products?[safe: 0] as? SKProduct`

Answer (score -1):

Please check the product array first like this
if(product.count > 0){
}
OR 
if let productarray_obj = self.fetchedProducts{
}

Answer (score -1):

You can use **Guard** to resolve the issue

```
guard let product = products?[0] as? SKProduct else {
    print("Something went wrong")
    return
}

let numberFormatter = NumberFormatter()
numberFormatter.formatterBehavior = NumberFormatter.Behavior.behavior10_4
numberFormatter.numberStyle = NumberFormatter.Style.currency
numberFormatter.locale = product.priceLocale

if let productPrice = numberFormatter.string(from: product.price) {
    self.purchaseFullVersionSubtitle.text = "Use this app forever for only \(productPrice)"
}
```

What Apple says about Guard

> Guard Statement
>
> A guard statement is used to transfer program control out of a scope
>   if one or more conditions aren’t met.
>
> A guard statement has the following form:
>
> ```
> guard condition else {
>
>     statements
>
> }
> ```